# Spring MVC and Hibernate throws Null Pointer exception occasionally

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm getting a NPE occasionally on the following code:
I'm a rookie in hibernate and and this was taken out of some tutorial that I don't recall:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<RawLine> getLastLines(){
            List<RawLine> result = null;
            Transaction tx = null;
            Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

            try{
                tx = session.beginTransaction();

// Line 54 is next:
            result = session.createCriteria(RawLine.class)
                             .add(Restrictions.eq("status", new Integer("0"))).list();

                tx.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }


            return result;

    }
```

Here is the exception.
It only happens sometimes, maybe one in every 5 or 10 times I load the page.

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[mvc-dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pt.itgest.readings.Readings.getLastLines(Readings.java:54)
    at pt.itgest.common.controller.LastReadingsController.printWelcome(LastReadingsController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Line 54. result = session.createCriteria(RawLine.class).add(Restrictions.eq("status", new Integer("0"))).list();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It was a hibernate problem with lazy loading on another class. Explicitly loaded the object with `Hibernate.initialize(object)` and this issue stopped.